# Deleting items in one-to-many relation in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, one-to-many

The following code works fine for adding new `ItemList`s and adding new `Items`s to the `ItemList`s. What I'm having issues with is deleting all items from a list. In other words I have a button (`deleteAllItems`) which is supposed to delete all items from the selected list, but the way I have it right now it deletes **ALL** `Item`s in `Realm` regardless of what list owns them.

What is the right way to create multiple `ItemList`s which would contain multiple `Item`s and have the ability to delete all `Item`s from a certain list?

#### ItemList Object:

```
class ItemList: Object {
    dynamic var listName = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let items = List<Item>()
}
```

#### Item Object:

```
class Item: Object {
    dynamic var productName = ""
    dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}
```

#### Main Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableListOfItems: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputProductName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputListName: UITextField!

    var allItems : Results<Item>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateData()
    }

    @IBAction func addNewList(_ sender: Any) {
        let list = ItemList()
        list.listName = inputListName.text!
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(list)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: Any) {
        let newItem = Item()
        newItem.productName = inputProductName.text!

        let list = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = 'List Name Here'").first!

        try! realm.write {
            list.items.append(newItem)
             updateData()
        }
    }

    func updateData(){
        allItems = realm.objects(Item.self)
        tableListOfItems.reloadData()
    }

     /// This deletes every Item in Realm which is not what
     /// I want. I want to delete only items that belong to 
     /// a certain list. I tried...
    /// let list = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = 'Default List'").first!
    /// list.items.removeAll()
    @IBAction func deleteAllItems(_ sender: Any) {
       try! realm.write {
           realm.delete(realm.objects(Item.self))
           updateData()
       }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        let data = allItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = data.productName
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
            if let item = allItems?[indexPath.row] {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(item)
                }
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your deleteAllItems function you should filter them. Without filtering this is the expected behaviour, since you only specify an object class, so Realm will obviously delete all objects matching that class.

If you want to delete all items from Realm itself that are contained in the List, but keep the empty list, you need to change your deleteAllItems function the following way:

```
@IBAction func deleteAllItems(_ sender: Any) {
       guard let listToDelete = realm.objects(ItemList.self).filter("listName = %@",listNameToDelete).first else { return }
       try! realm.write {
           for item in listToDelete.items {
               realm.delete(realm.objects(Item.self).filter("productName = %@", item.productName).first)
               updateData()
           }
       }
    }
```

listNameToDelete should be declared either outside your function in your class or you can declare it inside the function as well depending on what you actually want to achieve with this.
Also, this implementation assumes that your listNames and productNames are unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: FYI - I had to make the following change to the `for in` loop to make it work. `for item in (listToDelete?.items)!`. @ Dávid Pásztor - Quick question, what does the `= %@`  in `"listName = %@"` do?

Comment: I've updated my answer to safely unwrap the list, you shouldn't use force unwrapping, since if the list doesn't exist, your code will crash.
"%@ is a var arg substitution for an object value—often a string, number, or date" - from [Apple's Predicate Format String Syntax document](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-CJBDBHCB)